# Horizontal scroll between several UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, horizontalscrollview

I need to display students timetable in an application; a TableView contains a complete week, from Monday to Sunday. I'd like the student to be able to go next week by swiping horizontally, finding a new UITableView filled with the new week.

In other words, I'd like to scroll like photos on Facebook, but with complete UITableView filled with pieces of data.

How to do this programatically? Embedding several UITableView in a UIScrollView?

Thanks a lot...

Sincerely,

Hervé

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before using a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled.

The other alternative which is slightly more complex but makes it easier to manage each individual table separately is to use a `UIPageViewController`.

It sits behind the view controller views sort of like a `TabBarController` or a `NavigationController`.

You manage it a bit like a `UITableView` in that it has a `datasource` and it will ask for the "view controller at index".

Examples of this being used are in the Photos app when you are looking at full size images.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `UIPageView` controller with `UIView`.... and you can use animations on those views whatever you like.